# API request not working ReferenceError: GetAddressForRandomNftSale is not defined

Tags: javascript, http, get, fetch-api

I am trying to run a GET request using an API but I am getting a reference error code when I run the script. I really appreciate any help with how to solve this!

ERROR MESSAGE:

> "ReferenceError: GetAddressForRandomNftSale is not defined"

FRONTEND CODE:
Press on click event for #button1 to display result in a textbox #result
Code below

```
import {GetAddressForRandomNFTSale} from 'backend/serviceModule' ;
    export function button1_click(event) {

    GetAddressForRandomNftSale($w("address").value)
        .then(address => { $w('#result').text})

}
```

BACKEND CODE:
The code to fetch the GET API request using "serviceModule.jsw"
Code below...

```
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch'; 

export function GetAddressForRandomNftSale(address) {
    const url = 'https://api.nft-maker.io/xxxx/xxxx/1/10000000'
    console.log("url: " + url) 

    return fecth(url, {method: 'get'})
      .then(response => response.json())
}
```

Documentation
API end points & documentation: https://api.nft-maker.io/swagger/index.html

Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your call of the api (the url) is not correct. It must be:

```
https://api.easy-nft-projects.io/GetAddressForRandomNftSale/<api_key>/<project_id>/<number_of_nfts>/<amount_in_lovelace>
```

So you are missing the `GetAddressForRandomNftSale` in your url.

Comment: Thank you! You are right I see I missed that. Unfortunately still get the same error after adding.

Comment: The error comes, if you dont have all parameters. It is also important to use use the correct type. So if you try to send an string at an int parameter, you will get this error. Try this: It should work (you will get an error, that the api key is not correct, but the call should work) https://api.easy-nft-projects.io/GetAddressForRandomNftSale/abcd/1/1/5000000